# Custom Unsigned Integer Limits and Roll-over

Tags: c#

I currently have need for a special datatype in C#. I need the datatype to be an integer that can hold a value between 0-151. I already know that I can clamp the min and max spectrums, but I want it to be a roll-over feature instead of a limit clamp, kind of like how an unsigned integer wraps back around to 0 when it hits it's limit. One thing I can't figure out is how to handle the overflow. What I mean is something like this: Suppose the value is at 150 and I += 5. The value would wrap back around to zero and then add the remainder, which is 4. How do I do that without it being too computationally expensive?

How would you implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap up a modulo 151 (`% 151`) inside a struct, and declare it something like:

```
struct UIntCustom {
    public uint Value { get; private set; }

    public UIntCustom(uint value) : this() {
        Value = value % 151;
    }

    public static UIntCustom operator +(UIntCustom left, UIntCustom right) {
        return new UIntCustom(left.Value + right.Value);
    }

    public static UIntCustom operator -(UIntCustom left, UIntCustom right) {
        return new UIntCustom(left.Value - right.Value);
    }

    // and so on 

    public static explicit operator UIntCustom (uint c) {
        return new UIntCustom(c);
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
UIntCustom c = new UIntCustom(4);
Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
c -= (UIntCustom) 9;
Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
c += (UIntCustom) 150;
Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
```

Outputs:

```
4
150
149
```

Comment: Would the modulus operator work for underflow as well?

Comment: For underflow this implementation depends upon the behavior of `uint`. It does work.

Comment: @Krythic I added an example run through with output so you can see the results. It behaves are over/underflow would behave on a more traditional number. If that doesn't match up with what you're expecting, some clarification would be good  :)

Comment: Nope; looks spot on. I already accepted you as the answer, too. =)

Answer (score 5):

Do the sum, then perform `% 151`.

`x += 5`

is implemented as

`x = (x + 5) % 151`

Comment: This is so elegant. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a new struct and [operator overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) could be the way to go.