# Wrap integer value limit by range

Tags: c#, math, range

I'm trying to wrap an integer value's range so that, if it exceeds the maximum, the remaining amount to be added will increase from the minimum. The range should be between and including 0 and 9.

I've looked at the clamp function, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

If it helps, here's an example of what should happen:

```
int n1 = 8;

n1 += 4;
//n1 should equal 2

n1 -= 6;
//n1 should equal 6

n1 += 4;
//n1 should equal 0
```

Comment: So here you assume the max is `10` and you want whatever exceeds `10`. To start from `0` and vice versa with `0` as the min ? Please edit your question so that it makes more sense. I think you need to implement this. I do not think such a function exists.

Comment: I've edited the question so that it makes better sense

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089983/custom-unsigned-integer-limits-and-roll-over) question. The accepted answer provides a code snipped that might work for you with a little modification.

Comment: @Steve he has a min and max which have to reset when exceeded from the top and from the bottom so that `2 - 6 = 6` instead of `-4` and `8 + 4 = 2` instead of `12`.

Comment: What you're looking for is the mathematical modulo operator (sadly this is not inplemented in c# out of the box). However this answer shows the calculation that accomplishes this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2691042/10608418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
public int Normalize(int value, int modulo)
{
    int remainder = (value % modulo);

    return (remainder < 0) ? (modulo + remainder) : remainder;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vf8xoc)

```
int n1 = 8;

n1 = Normalize(n1 + 4, 10);
Console.WriteLine(n1);

n1 = Normalize(n1 - 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine(n1);

n1 = Normalize(n1 + 4, 10);
Console.WriteLine(n1);
```

Prints

```
2
6
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put the algorithm in a function with the variable as a reference:

```
void SpecialIncrease(ref int n, int increment, int min, int max)
{
    if (n + increment > max)
        n += increment - max - 1;
    else if (n + increment < min)
        n += max + 1 + increment;
    else
        n += increment;
}
```

And the main code:

```
int min = 0;
int max = 9;
int n = 8;

SpecialIncrease(ref n, 4, min, max); // 2
SpecialIncrease(ref n, -6, min, max); // 6
SpecialIncrease(ref n, 4, min, max); // 0
```